# How to call two divs at a same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a html page in which i have two divs one is page-role and other is with css alignment. 
Now i  have a button onclick of on the  button i want to open these divs at the same time. Because i want to trigger the situation of  div with page-role so that i can get the page focus-in and focus-out situations. If i directly move to div in side of page-role' div i am unable to get the page-role situation.
And if i directly call div with page-role the css alignment which i have set on "fullpage" div will be vanished.

But i don't understand how to do it:

Js code for button:

```
<Button id="button_to_click"  onclick="home_function();">Button Click</Button>
<script>
function home_function()
{ 
window.location.href ='index.html#fullpage';
}
</script>
```

when click on this button a new page is open:
in index page i have these divs:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div id="fullpage">
</div>
</div>
```

Record for div with page role "Page1"

```
$(document).on('pageinit','#page1', function(){
  console.log("init called");
$("#page1").focusin(function (){
  console.log("received 222 focus In Event");
})
$("#page1").focusout(function (){
  console.log("received 2222 focus Out Event");
})
});
```

Comment: your question is not clear, could you explain what you want and what you are getting ?

Comment: you want to open an external page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a multiple selection with jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Example:

```
$("#divA, #divB").show(); // displays #divA and #divB
```

You can combine events as well:

```
$("#page1").on("focusin focusout", function() {
    alert("focusin or focusout");
});
```

You could avoid using window.location.href by using links instead of buttons.

Comment: thanks for the help. Actually i want to open these divs from home page with window.location.href so how to do it. Actually i have two page one is home page in which i have this button and the other is index.html in which i have these divs

Comment: Please post your code at JSFiddle.net and describe exactly what you would like to do. It's a little bit confusing right now. ;)